# Trouble with ActionListener and an IF statement

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtextfield, decrement

I am currently having two problems both at which i have been trying to solve for the past 3 hours.

1. I cant get the `input--;` to decrement `if input is not == to 0`
2. I cant get the `JTextField input` to update the the value i assign to it once the program is running. Ill type 22 in the running program click start and it will go to "test99".[image] Pictures is an example of how i entered the value 66 then i pressed start and test99 came up instead of test66

I hope I was able to explain my problem to an extent you will be able to understand. I have read a lot of documentation about action listeners but currently the idea wont click for me. Any constructive criticism is welcome.

I also simplified my problem down as best as I could.

```
package test;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class test {

private JFrame frame;
private JButton btnStart;

/**
 * 
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                test window = new test();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public test() {
    initialize();
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 */

private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    JLabel Output = new JLabel("Time left: ");
    Output.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Output, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    JTextField Input = new JTextField();
    btnStart = new JButton("start");

    Input.setText("99");
    int input = (int) (Double.parseDouble(Input.getText()));

    Input.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    frame.getContentPane().add(Input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    Input.setColumns(10);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnStart, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Input.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

          }
        });


    Timer t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            Output.setText("test" + input);

            if (input == 0) {
                ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
            }
            input--;
        }

    });

    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            t.start();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Could you include a picture of the issue?

Comment: @Queue Does that give you a better idea?

Comment: The lines : `String t = Input.getText();` and `Input.setText(t);` make no sense. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Hackerdarshi it was guess work to try to figure my problem out I meant to delete that part its all fixed sorry!

Comment: Hint: please study java coding guidelines. Class names always start Uppercase. And you know, having two variables named input and Input only does thing: add confusion, and thus increase the likelihood for bugs dramatically!

Comment: @Jägermeister Im sorry for the confusion this was made in about 3 min. for demonstration purposed could you help with getting the textfield to update so Input is equal to what i set it as when i run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommand to declare your input variables not in your function, but in your class. Otherwise you run into scope problems. Example:

```
public class test {

  private JFrame frame;
  private JButton btnStart;
  private int input;
  private JTextField Input;

  //...

}
```

Should fix the issue :)

I am not enterily sure about the second issue but if you want to count down from the entered value, you have to update your action listener:

```
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        input = (int) (Double.parseDouble(Input.getText()));
        t.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: that fixed the problem with the decrement thank you very much any idea about the action listener for the JTextField Input?

Comment: @Jakob991 I am not enterily sure whether i understoof you correctly but i updated my post

Comment: You understood perfectly thank you for putting time aside to help me!

Answer (score 0):

There are several criticisms I have for your code:

1. variable names should start with a lowercase letter, and class names should start with an uppercase letter.
2. `int input = (int) (Double.parseDouble(Input.getText()));` Why use `Double.parseDouble` and then cast to an `int` when you can just use `Integer.parseInt()`?
3. "test99" comes up in your GUI instead of "test66" because you set the text of the input `JTextField` to 99, then parse that value **once** and then use it in your timer. You **never** update this value so it is **always** 99. Instead of this you should parse the text in the input `JTextField` every time the user presses "Start" and update the `int` value that your timer uses.

See my corrected solution below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test {

    private Test() {
        initialize();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(Test::new);
    }

    private void initialize() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        JPanel timePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        timePanel.add(new JLabel("Time left: "));

        JLabel timeOutput = new JLabel("");
        timePanel.add(timeOutput);

        frame.add(timePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");

        JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);

        JTextField timeField = new JTextField(5);

        inputPanel.add(startButton);
        inputPanel.add(stopButton);
        inputPanel.add(timeField);

        frame.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        Timer timer = new Timer();

        startButton.addActionListener(e -> {

            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);

            timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

                int time = Integer.parseInt(timeField.getText());

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(time < 0) timer.cancel();
                    timeOutput.setText(String.valueOf(time--));
                }
            }, 0, 1000);
        });

        stopButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            timer.cancel();
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            startButton.setEnabled(true);
            timeOutput.setText("");
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```